# Better place to setup an initialisation in SailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm new to Sails and don't know exactly where to put the initialisation of an object to be unique in all the app. After reading the docs I assumed that I can have it in the global `sails` object, but not sure if is the better place.

I'm using the new Appcelerator ArrowDB to store my users and objects. Docs talk about declare the appropriate vars and use it, with the APP_KEY.

```
var ArrowDB = require('arrowdb'),
    arrowDBApp = new ArrowDB('<App Key>');
function login(req, res) {
    var data = {
        login: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password,
        // the req and res parameters are optional
        req: req,
        res: res
    };
    arrowDBApp.usersLogin(data, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Login error:" + (err.message || result.reason));
        } else {
            console.log("Login successful!");
            console.log("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(result.body.response.users[0]));
        }
    });
}
```

But I will need to use constantly that `arrowDBApp` var to create, update, delete objects in the database, so I think the best way is to initialize it in the starting script `app.js` and share across the app.

I tried it, but I was not able to store it in the `sails` var, it seems that this var is not available (or lose its config) until sails.lift() is executed.

This code (app.js file) shows nothing in the console:

```
// Ensure we're in the project directory, so relative paths work as expected
// no matter where we actually lift from.
process.chdir(__dirname);

// Ensure a "sails" can be located:
(function() {
  var sails;
  try {
    sails = require('sails');
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('To run an app using `node app.js`, you usually need to have a version of `sails` installed in the same directory as your app.');
    console.error('To do that, run `npm install sails`');
    console.error('');
    console.error('Alternatively, if you have sails installed globally (i.e. you did `npm install -g sails`), you can use `sails lift`.');
    console.error('When you run `sails lift`, your app will still use a local `./node_modules/sails` dependency if it exists,');
    console.error('but if it doesn\'t, the app will run with the global sails instead!');
    return;
  }

  // Try to get `rc` dependency
  var rc;
  try {
    rc = require('rc');
  } catch (e0) {
    try {
      rc = require('sails/node_modules/rc');
    } catch (e1) {
      console.error('Could not find dependency: `rc`.');
      console.error('Your `.sailsrc` file(s) will be ignored.');
      console.error('To resolve this, run:');
      console.error('npm install rc --save');
      rc = function () { return {}; };
    }
  }

  // My own code
  var APP_KEY = 'mykey';
  var ArrowDB = require('arrowdb');
  sails.arrowDBApp = new ArrowDB(APP_KEY);
  console.log("Hi" + JSON.stringify(sails));

  // Start server
  sails.lift(rc('sails'));
  console.log("Finish");
})();
```

No "HI" and no "Finish" are printed. If I try to use `sails.arrowDBApp` in another controller, it is undefined.

Tips are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `config/bootstrap.js` to initialize something before Sails lifted. Sometimes if we want to put something in `global` variable, this approach is good to use, like define/ override native `Promise` with `Bluebird Promise`.
2. Use `api/services` to put some method or other things that you will use regularly in your code (controllers, models, etc.), like `Mail Service`, that handle sending email within your application.
3. Use config at `config` folder to predefined something at `sails.config[something]`. It can be an object, function, or whatever in order to become configurable, like put Twitter API Key to use Twitter REST API.

To achieve what you wanted, I'll try to use service and bootstrap.js. Try this example.

1. Create service file at `api/services/ArrowDBService.js`
2. Put with this code:

   ```
   var ArrowDB    = require('arrowdb'),
       arrowDBApp = new ArrowDB('<App Key>');

   module.exports = {
       arrowDBApp : arrowDBApp,
       login      : function (req, res) {
           var data = {
               login: req.body.username,
               password: req.body.password,
               // the req and res parameters are optional
               req: req,
               res: res
           };
           arrowDBApp.usersLogin(data, function(err, result) {
               if (err) {
                   console.error("Login error:" + (err.message || result.reason));
               } else {
                   console.log("Login successful!");
                   console.log("UserInfo: " + JSON.stringify(result.body.response.users[0]));
               }
           });
       }
   };
   ```

Now you can use it by `sails.services.arrowdbservice.login(req,res)` or simply `ArrowDBService.login(req,res)` (notice about case sensitive thing). Since I don't know about ArrowDB, so you may explore by yourself about `login` method that your example provide.

Comment: Thanks @Andi. With your way, the line `arrowDBApp = new ArrowDB('<App Key>');` will be executed every time? What I'm looking for is to execute that line only once (like a Singleton) and have `arrowDBApp` as a var available to all controllers, to later execute `arrowDBApp.usersCreate()`, `arrowDBApp.usersUpdate()`, etc.

Comment: AFAIK It's singleton.

Comment: I'm thinking that this way is not valid for my purposes, because I'm looking for a "shared" `arrowDBApp` to use in other controllers, and this way I share the functions directly (it's not what I want)

Comment: Just put `arrowDBApp` instead.

Comment: Great, that also works, as the @galactocalypse answer. Elegant solution. So I only need to choose between the easiest (put in bootstrap and save in sails global object), the `config` option or the `service` option. Thank you both for teach me this ways.

Comment: No problems. Nice to know if it helped.

Answer (score 6):

It's not advisable to modify `app.js` unless you really need to.

The usual space to save all configuration information (e.g. the `APP_KEY`) is in the [config](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration) directory in your project root.

One-time initializations (e.g. ArrowDB initialization) can be added to [config/bootstrap.js](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-bootstrap).

**Update**

In config/arrowdb.js (you need to create this file yourself):

```
module.exports.arrowdb = {
   APP_KEY: 'yourappkey',
   ArrowDBApp: null
};
```

In config/bootstrap.js:

```
var ArrowDB = require('arrowdb');

module.exports.bootstrap = function(next){
    sails.config.arrowdb['ArrowDBApp'] = new ArrowDB(sails.config.arrowdb['APP_KEY']);
    next(); // Don't forget to add this
};
```

In your controller:

```
'task': function(req, res, next) {
    sails.config.arrowdb['ArrowDBApp'].usersLogin(...);
    // and so on.
    // You could also add something like 
    // var ADB = sails.config.arrowdb['ArrowDBApp'];
    // at the top in case you need to use it on and on.
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I add arrowDB initialization to bootstrap, how can I use later in another controller. E.g. in `usersController.js` I need to call `create` in the form `arrowDBApp.usersCreate()`

Comment: `require` is cached and the `arrowDBApp = new ArrowDB('<App Key>');` will be executed only once? If yes, then it will be what I'm searching for.

Comment: I deleted the previous comment because it was in the wrong context and I was thinking of `arrowdb` instead of `arrowDBApp`. `arrowDBApp = new ArrowDB('<App Key>');` will be executed only once if it is in bootstrap.js. To access `arrowDBApp` globally, I would suggest adding it to the config file containing the `APP_KEY`. That way it will be accessible everywhere and be initialized only once.

Comment: In the config file... which of the 16 .js files inside config folder?

Comment: Hmm, you give me an idea. This was my final code (and is working, although I would like not to use global var `sails`): ```module.exports.bootstrap = function(cb) {
  var APP_KEY = 'mykey';
  var ArrowDB = require('arrowdb');
  sails.arrowDBApp = new ArrowDB(APP_KEY);}``` Now I can use in other controllers simply doing `sails.arrowDBApp.APICall()`

Comment: Create a new file and name it anything (e.g. arrowdb.js). It will be imported automatically and will be available throughout the project as `sails.config.arrowdb`. I'm updating my answer to show how exactly I think you should go about it. Give me five minutes.

Comment: You new response seems more right but less easy to implement. It's my approach incorrect? I only need to use `sails.arrowDBApp.APICall()` every time instead `sails.config.arrowdb['ArrowDBApp'].APICall()`. Why to use config if you can use straight bootstrap and globalize it (will be always a read object)? Thank you for your clarifications, I learned a lot.

Comment: Glad you did. It's just that `sails.arrowDBApp` can make it difficult for someone else to figure out where the variable was actually declared/initialized. Apart from that I can't really think of any downsides at the moment.